# Unchecked CheckBox in jsPDF AcroForms

Tags: jspdf

The [examples of jsPDF AcroForm fields in the jsPDF documentation](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/b9f932cd2e22c82db0a39f0225521945a2568809/examples/js/acroforms.js) show how to create a CheckBox field but that field is always checked initially. How do you create a CheckBox that initializes to unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around in the PDF spec ([ISO 32000-1:2008](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) I found in section 12.7.4.2.3 that the checked and unchecked appearances correspond to entries in the field's appearance dictionary. I downloaded this PDF generated by jsPDF:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('CheckBox:', 10, 125);
var checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.fieldName = "CheckBox1";
checkBox.Rect = [50, 120, 30, 10];
checkBox.value = 'Yes'
doc.addField(checkBox);
```

I opened the PDF in a text editor and found my field definition:

```
<<
/F 4
/Rect [141.73 473.39 226.77 501.73]
/FT /Btn
/T (CheckBox1)
/DA (/F13 0 Tf 0.000 g)
/V /Yes
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Widget
/Q 1
/MK <<
/CA (3)
>>
/AS /On
/AP <<
/N <</On 7 0 R >>/D <</On 8 0 R /Off 9 0 R >>>>
>>
```

The /N there is the dictionary and the AS value is whether the CheckBox is checked or not. So this means you can control the appearance with:

```
checkBox.appearanceState = 'Off' //unchecked
checkBox.appearanceState = 'On' //checked
```

Comment: @Jared Can you elaborate? It's working for me on the jsPDF demo site (http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/) using Chrome 77

Comment: I think I just needed to upgrade to 1.5.3

Comment: Have you figured out how to set the font size of TextField() ?   I've tried everything,  even downloading and altering the library.

Comment: I've also posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594041/how-to-edit-font-size-for-textfield-in-jspdf

Answer (score 1):

Dedicated to all developers from the future.

[AcroFormCheckBox is defined in the official repository](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/modules/acroform.js) on line 2348. Correct values for the `value` and `appearanceState` property are either `On` or `Off`.

The provided solution lead to inconsitent visualization of the checkbox in respect to the internal `value` and thus to errors on the PDF importing side.

Correct solution:

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.fieldName = "CheckBox1";
checkBox.Rect = [50, 120, 30, 10];
checkBox.value = 'Off'; // or On
checkBox.appearanceState = 'Off'; // or On
doc.addField(checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two very simple variants that I have made use of:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

function checkbox(x, y, length, width) {
doc.rect(x, y, length, width);
doc.line(x, y, x + length, y + width);
doc.line(x, y + length, x + width, y);
}

doc.text(10, 28, 'Checked')
checkbox(10, 30, 2, 2);
checkbox(20, 30, 4, 4);
checkbox(35, 30, 8, 8);
checkbox(55, 30, 12, 12);

doc.text(10, 48, 'Unchecked')
doc.rect(10, 50, 2, 2);
doc.rect(20, 50, 4, 4);
doc.rect(35, 50, 8, 8);
doc.rect(55, 50, 12, 12);
```

Result:
[What the checkbox looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSHvD.png)