# How to edit Font Size for TextField() in JSPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Good morning,
Has anyone been able to edit the font size on a `TextField()` in JSPDF?
I don't care if multi-line is true or false, I just need to be able to set the default font size of a `TextField()`.

Here's my code, which comes from https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/acroforms.js:

```
doc.text('TextField:', 10, 145);
var textField = new TextField();
textField.Rect = [50, 140, 30, 10];
textField.multiline = true;
textField.value = "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse";//
textField.fieldName = "TestTextBox";
doc.addField(textField);
```

things I've tried:

1. `doc.setFontSize(10);`  set this before adding the field of course. no effect on textfield font size
2. `textField.fontSize = 10`   no effect on textfield font size
3. `textField.setFontSize(10)`  throws error

I even tried downloading the library and altering it but couldn't get that to work.

I also tried playing around on the testing site:
http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

I found a similar question on GitHub but it was not asked well nor addressed:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/981

I'm using the latest debug build: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default jsPDF behavior is to increase the font size to fill the TextField. You can prevent this by setting a maxFontSize like this:

```
doc.text('TextField:', 10, 145);
var textField = new TextField();
textField.Rect = [50, 140, 30, 10];
textField.multiline = true;
textField.value = "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse";//
textField.fieldName = "TestTextBox";

//SET FONT SIZE
textField.maxFontSize = 9;

doc.addField(textField);
```

Hope this helps. The documentation is pretty sparse but can be found here: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-AcroForm-AcroFormTextField.html

Comment: perfect. textField.maxFontSize = 9; is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: This is not working with latest version of jspdf 2